# Cannot grant privileges to a user on a database

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm baffled by the problem I'm having. I created a database, created a user, and want to grant the user all privileges on the database. One way or another, I'm having syntax errors, while I'm fairly sure there is no syntax error.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT User FROM mysql.user;
+------------+
| User       |
+------------+
| osticket   |
| phpmyadmin |
| root       |
+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| osticket           |
| performance_schema |
| phpmyadmin         |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'osticket'.* TO 'osticket'@localhost;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''osticket'.* TO 'osticket'@localhost' at line 1
MariaDB [(none)]>
```

I also changed localhost to 'localhost' to be sure, no avail. What's going on here?

Comment: @jarlh I'm still learning SO, why is the 'SQL'  tag not appropriate?

Comment: It's very MySQL specific, and not useful at all for other dbms products. "_If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL._"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `osticket`.* TO 'osticket'@localhost;
```

be aware of the quotations

```
`osticket`.*
```

Comment: I must be blind, but there are quotations in my SQL? The error even shows them: near ''osticket'.* TO 'osticket'@localhost'

The error seems to show double quotation marks before the first osticket, but that's an extra quotation mark that ends at the end of the error quote.

Comment: mysql puts that double quotation marks. what you need here is `

Comment: Thanks, that's the solution indeed, what is the charcode of that mark? I don't even know how to reproduce this on an AZERTY lay-out.

Comment: https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/34275547-provide-alternative-to-backtick-markdown-for-non-q